# Default value in drop down menu in Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am building a web application using Spring MVC and thymeleaf. My drop down menu is like this and it works as expected:

```
<form style="display: inline-block" th:action="@{/search}"
                th:object="${searchForm}" th:method="post">
                <select th:field="*{selectedOption}">
                    <option th:each="option : ${searchOptions}"
                        th:value="${option.getOption()}"
                        th:text="${option.getOptionName()}">Options</option>
                </select> <input type="text" th:field="*{criteria}" name="searchTextBox"
                    class="topcoat-text-input--large" /> <input type="submit"
                    style="display: inline-block" class="topcoat-button--large--cta"
                    value="Search" name="searchButton" />
            </form>
```

But how can I set a pre-selected/default value for the drop down menu?

Thanks

EDIT 1:

I tried adding this: `th:selected="${searchCriteria.getSelectedOption()}"`to have it be:

```
<select th:field="*{selectedOption}">
                        <option th:each="option : ${searchOptions}"
                            th:value="${option.getOption()}"
                            th:text="${option.getOptionName()}"
                            th:selected="${searchCriteria.getSelectedOption()}">Options</option>
                    </select>
```

But this still does not set the default value to what is selected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose that `searchCriteria.getSelectedOption()` doesn't return boolean value, but it has to.

Edit:

```
<select th:field="*{selectedOption}">
    <option th:each="option : ${searchOptions}"
            th:value="${option.getOption()}"
            th:text="${option.getOptionName()}"
            th:selected="${searchCriteria.isSelected(option)}">
        Options
    </option>
</select>
```

In your SearchCriteria class (I don't know how it actually look like):

```
public boolean isSelected(Option option) {
    return option.equals(selectedOption);
}
```

Comment: Oh it has to return a boolean value? really?

Comment: I thought th:selected just automatically sets a value in the drop down list when the page loads

Comment: The th:selected attribute must evaluate to boolean value, see http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#fixed-value-boolean-attributes. When it evaluates to true, then Thymeleaf simply renders HTML "selected" attribute.

Comment: Of course it wouldn't make sense to return boolean value from "getSelectedOption". You should compare current value with selected one or create new method, that checks if current value is selected.

Comment: Ok can you give me an example usage pls?

Comment: Answer edited. I don't know how your classes actually look like, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: http://forum.thymeleaf.org/form-select-th-field-and-th-selected-not-working-how-do-you-set-default-value-td4030583.html

Answer (score 4):

This post has been open a while but figured I would add my findings in case someone wants an alternative approach. In my case I had a list of tasks that were saved in the DB, each having a size of 1-10 that represented the tasks complexity. On page load, Thymeleaf injects the model (a list of tasks) to the UI, and I had to have the size of each task pre-loaded in the drop-down lists. The below code did the trick for me.

**Task.java**

```
private int size;

private static int[] complexity = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

//getters and setters of course for each of the above variables
```

**HTML**

```
//for each task element in the UI, create the dropdown and pre-populate the selected value
<select id="size">
     <option th:each="size : ${task.complexity}"
         th:value="${size}"
         th:selected="${task.size} == ${size} ? true : false"
         th:text="${size}">
     </option>
</select>
```